# Why when I add POLLHUP as event, WSAPoll returns error (invalid arguments)?

Tags: c, winsock

I'm using WSAPoll for my project. I used tracking POLLIN and POLLOUT events. Everything worked nice. When I add POLLHUP as event, WSAPoll returns error 10022 (Invalid argument).

I've no idea what's wrong, please guide me how to fix it:(

`cc_qnt` - quantity of connected clients

```
        int ev_cnt = WSAPoll(pfd, cc_qnt + 1, 100);
        if (ev_cnt > 0) { 

            for (i = 0; i < cc_qnt; i++)  {   

                if (pfd[i].revents & POLLHUP) {      

                    // some code
                } 

                if (pfd[i].revents & POLLIN) {

                    // some code
                }
            } 

            if (pfd[cc_qnt].revents & POLLIN) {
```

In this part we have new connection ready for accepting. We edit `pfd[cc_qnt]` adding new socket (returned by accept) instead of listening socket. Then we reallocate pfd with size + 1, copying previous data and adding listening socket at the end of cc array.

```
                int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
                cc[cc_qnt].s = accept(ls, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &addrlen);
                cc[cc_qnt].ip = ntohl(addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
                cc[cc_qnt].sent_put = 0;
                cc[cc_qnt].c_cl_cn = 0;

                pfd[cc_qnt].fd = cc[i].s;
                pfd[cc_qnt].events = POLLIN | POLLOUT | POLLHUP;

                cc_qnt++;
                pfd = init_pfd(pfd, ls, cc_qnt);
            }   
        }   
        else if (ev_cnt < 0) {    

            exit(printf("\nprocess_events: WSAPoll, ev_cnt = %d, WSAGetLastError: %d \n", ev_cnt, WSAGetLastError()));
        }
```

Everything I changed for tracking POLLHUP - adding it's bit to  pfd[cc_qnt].events and WSAPoll started returning error. I expect tracking POLLHUP event.

Comment: The `cc_qnt + 1` doesn't look right. Why the plus 1?

Comment: In cc array we have cc_qnt of connected clients sockets and one listening socket. +1 is for the last one

Comment: FYI, you really should stay away from `WSAPoll()`, [it is broken](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/10/10/wsapoll-is-broken/) (also [see this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/18769abd-fca0-4d3c-9884-1a38ce27ae90/wsapoll-and-nonblocking-connects-to-nonexistent-ports): "*The recommendation for now is to not use the WSAPoll function it in case you encounter this issue, but rather the other Net-API functions.*"). There are better ways to work with non-blocking/asynchronous sockets on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`WSAPoll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsapoll) documentation:

> `WSAEINVAL`
>
> An invalid parameter was passed. This error is returned if the `fdarray` parameter contains a `NULL` pointer. **This error is also returned if invalid flags were specified in the `events` member of any of the [`WSAPOLLFD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/ns-winsock2-pollfd) structures pointed to by the `fdarray` parameter when requesting socket status**. This error is also returned if none of the sockets specified in the `fd` member of any of the [`WSAPOLLFD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/ns-winsock2-pollfd) structures pointed to by the `fdarray` parameter were valid.

And per the [`WSAPOLLFD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/ns-winsock2-pollfd) documentation:

> `events`
>
> Type: `short`
>
> A set of flags indicating the type of status being requested. **This must be one or more of the following.**
>
> `POLLPRI`
>     Priority data may be read without blocking. This flag is not supported by the Microsoft Winsock provider.
>
> `POLLRDBAND`
>   Priority band (out-of-band) data can be read without blocking.
>
> `POLLRDNORM`
>   Normal data can be read without blocking.
>
> `POLLWRNORM`
>   Normal data can be written without blocking.
>
> The `POLLIN` flag is defined as the combination of the `POLLRDNORM` and `POLLRDBAND` flag values. The `POLLOUT` flag is defined as the same as the `POLLWRNORM` flag value.

So, as you can see, `POLLHUP` is not documented as being a valid flag for *input* to `WSAPoll()`.  Indeed, it does not match any of the above flags defined in `winsock2.h`:

```
/* Event flag definitions for WSAPoll(). */

#define POLLRDNORM  0x0100
#define POLLRDBAND  0x0200
#define POLLIN      (POLLRDNORM | POLLRDBAND)
#define POLLPRI     0x0400

#define POLLWRNORM  0x0010
#define POLLOUT     (POLLWRNORM)
#define POLLWRBAND  0x0020

#define POLLERR     0x0001
#define POLLHUP     0x0002
#define POLLNVAL    0x0004
```

`POLLHUP` is, however, documented as an *output* flag in the `revents` member of `WSAPOLLFD`:

> `revents`
>
> Type: `short`
>
> A set of flags that indicate, upon return from the WSAPoll function call, the results of the status query. This can a combination of the following flags.
>
> ...
>
> `POLLHUP`
>   A stream-oriented connection was either disconnected or aborted.
>
> ...

This matches the use of `POLLHUP` in [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) on *nix platforms:

> `POLLHUP`
>   Hang up (**only returned in `revents`; ignored in `events`**).  Note
>   that when reading from a channel such as a pipe or a stream
>   socket, this event merely indicates that the peer closed its
>   end of the channel.  Subsequent reads from the channel will
>   return 0 (end of file) only after all outstanding data in the
>   channel has been consumed.

So, you don't need to (and on Windows, you cannot) explicitly request `POLLHUP`, you just get it for free.